# How to generate random meaningless, but at the same time easy to remember words?

Tags: java, php, string, algorithm

I need to figure out an algorithm or, even better, if there is an implementation in php/java to generate words which will be suggested to user to choose like some identifiers but I want them to be somewhat easy to remember, eg 'wonifuxa', 'thonqi', 'oqriman' and so on but not something like 'nxdFgtqI'

Comment: Do it by sticking together syllables. Build the syllables by sticking together phonemes (or just letters) in pronouncible combinations of consonants and vowels. Profit.

Comment: Isn't this a bit subjective? Easy to remember for whom? I am guessing the problem will solve itself when you try and define what easy to remember means for you...

Comment: Put voice recognition software up to a toddler and hit record.

Comment: @Moron: it's not as subjective as you'd think; see links at [Joe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108248/how-to-generate-random-meaningless-but-at-the-same-time-easy-to-remember-words/5108418#5108418)'s asnwer.

Comment: @Eelvex: What is pronounceable for Chang might not be for Smith. It is subjective and IMO, the main issue to be solved here is defining what easy means...

Comment: @Moron: It *is* subjective but not *as* subjective as one would think. Eg: `xzxlzyw` is difficult for 96.5% of people whereas `ana` is easy for the same percentage.

Comment: @Eel: Now where did you pull that ridiculous number from? Anyway, pointless conversation. Please pardon me if I don't respond.

Comment: I have to mention this by way of a caveat...or just amusement value: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a function that generates random words like you are describing.  It doesn't use the letter "Q" because that one kept making unpronounceable words.

```
<?php
    //generate random consonants separated by vowels
    function generate_faux_word($letters = 5){

        //define arrays of consonants and vowels
        //no q, it's tough to remember
        $consonants = array('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
        $vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

        $ret_word = "";
        $consonant_toggle = true;
        //randomly choose a consonant then a vowel until the word is as long as the parameter
        while(strlen($ret_word) < $letters){
            if ($consonant_toggle){
                $ret_word .= $consonants[array_rand($consonants)];
                $consonant_toggle = false;
            }else{
                $ret_word .= $vowels[array_rand($vowels)];
                $consonant_toggle = true;
            }

        }

        return $ret_word;
    }

    echo generate_faux_word();
    echo "<br />";
    echo generate_faux_word();
    echo "<br />";
    echo generate_faux_word(6);
    echo "<br />";
    echo generate_faux_word(4);

?>
```

A sample output is:
muher
sucok
kozive
xaso

Answer (score 5):

There is a library for generating pronounceable words.  Here is a link to the library: http://www.multicians.org/thvv/gpw.html.  There is a link to the Java source file on that page.  I had found the python library for it first: http://www.preetk.com/node/pygpw-generate-pronouncable-words/

Comment: Great! Thank you for this solution, but another guy provided PHP solution, which actually works for me better at the time!

Answer (score 4):

Back in the days of telegraphs, when communication was charged per-letter, quite a few companies devised codes to encode entire sentences in as few letters as possible. Most of them had the same basic requirement: a collection of letters that was reasonably easy to remember. The usual rule was something like alternation between groups of a vowel and up to two consonants. This would allow (for example) "labdon", but not "aobldn" (same letters, different order). Almost any sequence you produce following a rule like this ends up reasonably easy to pronounce, so somebody can remember it as essentially a word instead of having to remember all the individual letters.

Answer (score 2):

## C#

```
    private static string RandomWord(int length)
    {
        var consonants = new[] { "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
        var vowels = new[] { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };
        var word = "";
        var b = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            word += b ? consonants[Rng.Next(consonants.Length)] : vowels[Rng.Next(vowels.Length)];
            b = !b;
        }
        return word;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary and choose two words. Split them at a random point and join them.

Example:

```
IDEA -> IDE
WITHOUT -> THOUT
-----------
IDETHOUT
```

for even better results, control the splitting point (eg first word: split at a vowel, second word: split before a consonant and in a way that resulting syllables = 3).

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a string one character at a time and have each character a random value between 97-122 (inclusive). These are the ascii decimal values for the letters a-z (non caps). And then of course convert them to string.

Although, whether or not this would work is based on your definition of "Easy to remember". They all look pretty hard to remember to me.

Answer (score 0):

Nonsense Word Generator. This was built using several different structures similar to what @Jerry Coffin was talking about. Fun, but not necessarily helpful! http://www.mygengen.com/gengens/view/nonsense-words

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function generateRandomString(){
  var consonants = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  var word = "";
  var b = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    word += b ? consonants[getRandomInt(consonants.length)] : vowels[getRandomInt(vowels.length)];
    b = !b;
  }
  return word;
}
```